# R: from file import foo as bar

Tags: r

I am looking for a technique that combines the following two questions:

> [Define all functions in one .R file, call them from another .R file. How, if possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548266/define-all-functions-in-one-r-file-call-them-from-another-r-file-how-if-pos)
>
> [The R equivalent of Python `from x import y as z`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334773/the-r-equivalent-of-python-from-x-import-y-as-z)

In other words, I want to import a specific function from someone else's `.r` file. Under a different name.

Comment: @musefan how can my question be made clearer?

Comment: Well you could write one for starters... you haven't put anything. You can't just link 2 questions and that's it. Your question needs to be able to stand on it's own, not rely on links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call `source` with `local=TRUE` inside a new function, and return only the needed function:

```
source1 <- function(path,fun){
  source(path, local= TRUE)
  get(fun)
}
```

`from x import y as z` will be written:

```
z <- source1(x,y) # where y is a string
```

Example:

```
# create 'test.R' file in working directory
write("test  <- function(a,b) a + b
      test2 <- function(a,b) a - b",
      "test.R")

new_fun <- source1("test.R","test2")

new_fun
# function(a,b) a - b
# <environment: 0x0000000014873f08>

test
# Error: object 'test' not found

test2
# Error: object 'test2' not found

# clean up
unlink("test.R")
```

Comment: How awesome is that?! I still can't get used to how things by default are global and mutable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `source` as follows:

In test.R script:

```
test <- function() message("Hello")
```

Then, source that file using

```
someone <- new.env()
source("test.R", someone)
```

To call someone's code, use

```
someone$test()
```

If possible, ask that someone to write a R package.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such mechanism in R.

Of course you can do

`x.R
      y <- function() {do_something}`

`z.R
      source("x.R")
      z <- y
      rm(y)`

A better options would be to make `x.R` into a package. Then you simple do `z <- x::y`

The best solution is to convert both `x.R` and `z.R` into packages and use `@importFrom x y` into package `z` and don't bother with changing the name of the function.